# For $Re(z)<0$, $|e^z-1|<|z|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Consider $Re(z)<0$, then $|e^z-1|<|z|$

I have solved the problem by estimation $|1-cos y|<|y^2/2|$ for any $y\in R$ and $|1-e^x|<|x|$ for $x<0$. One can solve $|e^z-1|=|e^{2x}-2e^x cos y+1|=|(e^x-1)^2+2e^x(1-cosy)|<|x^2+2y^2/2|=|z|$ where $Re(z)<0$. However, I found this method too cumbersome.

$\textbf{Q1 :}$ Is there an easier way to deduce this? Say by linear fraction transformation, or other estimation?(Note that $|e^z-1|<|z|$ boils down to prove $|\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}|<1$ for $Re(z)<0$ via taylor expansion. However I do not see any way to deal with this.)

$\textbf{Q2:}$ Why is $|\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}|<1$ for $Re(z)<0$? In other words, what is the fundamental reason that next leading order term dominates over the estimation?(e.g. $|1-cos y|<y^2/2$ and $|\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)}!|\leq 1$ where $1$ is the next leading order.)

Comment: Your calculation is wrong at two places. Please get it right.

Comment: @amsmath I should have written $|e^z-1|^2=\dots$ instead and $|x^2+2y^2/2|=|z|^2$. Is that all?

Comment: Nope. You have $x^2+2e^x\tfrac{y^2}2$ instead of $x^2+2\tfrac{y^2}2$.

Comment: @amsmath $x<0$. So this is upper bound estimation.

Comment: user45765 Ok...

Answer (score 1):

Put $f(z) = e^z$. Then
$$
|e^z-1| = |f(z)-f(0)| = \left|\int_0^z f'(w)\,dw\right| < |z|\max_{w\in [0,z]}|f'(w)| = |z|.
$$

Comment: Why is $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}<1$ then for $Re(z)<0$?

Comment: You mean $\left| \sum z^n/(n+1)!\right|$, of course, @user45765. It's very hard (maybe impossible) to see this way. How are you going to use $\text{Re}(z)<0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not see any obvious way to use $Re(z)<0$ information as I cannot pass absolute value inside the inequality or this will remove the condition $Re(z)<0$.

Comment: Agreed. Power series is not the right approach to this.

Comment: @TedShifrin The other thing, I saw is $|1-cos y|<y^2/2$ which has similar behavior.

Comment: @user45765: For that you can also use a mean value theorem proof, but because you're working with *real numbers* only and have an alternating series whose terms decrease in size, you know that the rest of the series is dominated by the next term.

Comment: @TedShifrin For real variable, intermediate value theorem works. I do recall there should be intermediate value theorem as inequality for higher dimensional function. So I would guess, I can try that one instead.

Comment: @user45765 If $x < 0$, then $|e^z| = |e^{x+iy}| = |e^xe^{iy}| = e^x < 1$.